# Prove $(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \to (q \lor r)$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am looking for a way to prove that the statement,

$$(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \to (q \lor r)$$

is a tautology without the help of the truth table, by using only laws and theorems like De Morgan's Law, Domination Law, etc. Also, I can't use the rules of inference. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from

$$(p∨q) ∧ (¬p∨r) → (q∨r) $$

Apply $(p\rightarrow q)\Leftrightarrow(\neg p\vee q)$ have

$$(\neg p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge r)\vee(q\vee r)$$

---

Notice $(\neg p\wedge q)$ and $(p\wedge r)$ are contradict to each other

That means one of them has to be true, therefore the whole statement will also be true

Which implies it's a tautology

---

Apply $(p\vee\neg p)\Leftrightarrow\top$ that

$$\top\vee (q\vee r)$$

Apply $(\top\vee p)\Leftrightarrow \top$ we have

$$\top\tag*{$\square$}$$